# DDOS Protection in Open Source MQTT Brokers

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I'm doing a research on DDOS protections in MQTT brokers and I started with open source Mosquitto broker. I couldn't find any countermeasure listed in the documentation page.

Since my C language knowledge is not that deep, I would like first ask this here before checking the source code. Are there any countermeasures against DDOS attacks in Mosquitto broker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DDOS protection should be at the network level, not in the application.

By the time it's made it down the TCP/IP stack to the application, it's too late and your machine is already on it's knees